# Multiple conditions & query cypher / apoc

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I ran following query to use multiple apoc.do.when but it seems only my first apoc.do.when is  executing

```
load csv from "file:///D:leads.csv"
as row
FIELDTERMINATOR ',' 
WITH row[0] as id,
row[1] as fname,
row[2] as lname,
row[4] as email1,
row[5] as email2,
row[6] as phone1,
row[7] as phone2,
row[8] as phone3,
split(row[11]," ") as birthDay
LIMIT 5

MERGE (l:Lead {id:id})
with l as leadRef,email1,email2,phone1,phone2,phone3,fname,lname,id

CALL apoc.do.when(email1 is not null,'MERGE (e1:Email {value:email}) MERGE (l)-[r:Has_Email]-> 
(e1)','',{email:email1,l:leadRef}) YIELD value WITH value AS 
ignored,leadRef,email1,email2,phone1,phone2,phone3,fname,lname,id

CALL apoc.do.when(phone1 is not null,'MERGE (p1:Phone {value:phone}) MERGE (l)-[r:Has_Phone]-> 
(p1)','',{phone:phone1,l:leadRef}) YIELD value WITH value AS 
ignored2,leadRef,email1,email2,phone1,phone2,phone3,fname,lname,id

CALL apoc.do.when(phone2 is not null,'MERGE (p2:Phone {value:phone}) MERGE (l)-[r:Has_Phone]-> 
(p2)','',{phone:phone2,l:leadRef}) YIELD value WITH value AS 
ignored3,leadRef,email1,email2,phone1,phone2,phone3,fname,lname,id

return true
```

is there a way to execute multiple query based on multiple condition ? without break in first statement

Comment: you can try apoc.do.case for that . its take list  of conditions and queries

Comment: Your second/third `apoc.do.when` calls are not supposed to do anything if `phone1`/`phone2` are null, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of UNION between each CALL apoc.do.when.